# Can't set Ubuntu 20.04 on XPS 13 9310 to deep sleep mode. Laptop keeps draining battery

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell, battery, xps

I am using a Dell XPS 13 9310 with an Ubuntu 20.04, and the battery keeps draining when supposed to be on suspend mode. It seems that the deep sleep issue came up many times in the past, and suggestions for solutions have been posted in different forums. However, non of the solutions work for me. The two main solutions that keep showing up are :

```
echo deep | sudo tee /sys/power/mem_sleep
```

which returns:

```
tee: /sys/power/mem_sleep: Invalid argument
```

Basically, the system doesn't let me change the `mem_sleep` from `[s2idle]` to `deep`.
The second solution is changing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

which doesn't seem to do much either.

I tried these solutions multiple times but the battery keeps draining when the laptop is suspended. Also the commend `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` keeps returning `[s2idle]`.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

Comment: Old now, but did you ever get this fixed?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this kernel bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211879#c24), it can be fixed by changing the disk mode from RAID to AHCI in BIOS.

Comment: Thanks! In the latest ubuntu update, the battery consumption improved. I will test your suggestion and see if it improves the performance.

Comment: Apparently, it was already on an AHCI mode

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently running Elementary OS Odin (Ubuntu 20.04) on my Dell XPS 15 9310 and I just found out that when you close the lid after suspend, it will not wake up when opening the lid the next day. It seems that after a few hours the system had turned off.

I had to disable the lidswitch in the bios (pressing F12 during boot).
Then I was able to suspend, close the lid, open de lid next day and press enter to wake up. Overall batterydrain was around 7%.

I suggest people to install powertop:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install powertop
```

Then calibrate with:

```
sudo powertop --calibrate
```

This has improved my battery usage.